# Is it possible to create a set function for an unsigned long which receives the buffer

Tags: c++

I would like to know if there is a way to create a set function for an unsigned long which receives the buffer (char|string) which way it will be the best way to do this.. I came up with this but is not taking my buffer and I am not sure if my logic is complete correct..

This is in my book.h file..

```
struct Book
{
    unsigned long rating;
}
```

This is in my book.cpp file

```
void Book::setRating(unsigned long newRating){
    isbn = newRating = std::strtoul(buffer, NULL, 0);
}
```

And this is in my app.cpp file

```
char buffer[5];
sprintf(buffer, "%lu", b.isbn);
b.setIsbn(buffer);
sprintf(buffer, "%lu", b.rating);
b.setRating(buffer);
```

Everything is good less the buffer handling to my setIsbn function and setRating function.. 
Please if you guys need something extra let me know and I will provide more info..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass `buffer` to `setRating`:

```
void Book::setRating(const char *buffer){
    isbn = std::strtoul(buffer, NULL, 0);
}
```

I'm not quite sure what you're doing with `buffer` in your `app.cpp`, but if you want to set the rating based on the contents of a C-style string, the above version of `setRating` will do that.